# Cost function: output layer should sum up to roughly 1

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a convolutional neural network classifying some images for me. The output layer is *not* one-hot encoded but outputs a distribution around the predicted class (because neighboring classes are semantically related). For the learning step a perfect gaussian/normal distribution is feeded to the network - centered at the correct class ($y_{teach}$).

My cost function is cross-entropy:

$$-\bigr(y_{teach} * log(y_{out}) + (1 - y_{teach}) * (1 - y_{out})\bigr)$$

Before calculating the cross-entropy the output is softmax'ed but only for the learning step. The normal output of the output layer in a feedforward step is linear / "unfiltered". My hope was that the network not only generates activity bumps around the real classes ($y_{teach}$) but also tries to learn that the sum has to be roughly 1 in total.

Unfortunately this doesn't really happen. The activity bumps are looking like a gaussian distribution in the first hundreds of epochs but with much noise.

If I train for some thousands epochs the distributions reduce in noise and get really soft and nice but due to overfitting(?!) the bumps get **really** high..like an activation of 3 to 5 in one single class.

So overall the network learns the right thing and predicts the right classes but the output layer does not sum up to 1 but to 100 or something like this after thousands of epochs (and this is not what I want, I want it to learn correct classes *and* that the sum of the output layer has to be roughly 1).

How would I model my cost function to punish solutions which have a sum highly greater than 1?

I thought of cross entropy plus something for punishing a sum greater one like this:

$$-\bigr(y_{teach} * log(y_{out}) + (1 - y_{teach}) * (1 - y_{out})\bigr) + \bigr|1 - sum(y_{out})\bigl|$$

...but now the network highly concentrates on the sum and more or less forgets about the distribution / classifier learning. Sometimes a nice distribution pops up but most of the time it just learns "crap" which sums up to 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried scaling the penalty? Something like cost + (s * (Abs(1-sum(Yout))) where s is your scaling factor.

Comment: So you think the penalty itself should work and scaling it should boost the performance?

Comment: The penalty was actually the first idea to pop into my head while reading your question. In theory it should work as long as your back propogation correctly takes the penalty into account. But how WELL it will work I couldn't tell you. If the scaling doesn't work so well, here is another idea. I think having a softmax only in the learning step might give inconsistent results. Have you tried using softmax on both training and validation? Also, have you tried using sigmoid outputs? or sigmoid + softmax?

Comment: I have tried softmax on both but with a big network and many epochs you are likely to get into mathematical side effects. Additionally I want my weights to be rather small and really try to model my output rather than having roughly "the direction to go for" and letting the softmax do the rest. I guess a sigmoid on the output might be interesting.

Comment: I am interested to hear if you find anything successful. I had an idea for a network that would need to do something similar, but haven't started working on it yet. good luck!

Comment: So far my attempts were not succesful :/ Will do more experiments tomorrow

Comment: To keep you updated: I've came up with an idea which *may* be promising. First results were not too bad...I am waiting for a slot on my universitys compute cluster at the moment. Will update when I have reasonable results.

Comment: And you managed to find a working solution?

Comment: @Pop Frobot sorry that I forgot to comment further. The idea of Frobot was actually good (scaling the penalty) it just did not work in a simple some of cost + scaled penalty. Instead, I used a equilibrium boundary, very similar to the idea by Berthelot et. al. in their BEGAN (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10717). This way both targets are weighed against each other and being considered.

Comment: Thanks again @Frobot for the input!